# Image preview in "design mode" on a View that has yet to be set programmatically

Tags: android, xml, button, imageview

I was wondering if there is an **xml tag** that allows me to see a **preview of an image** in the *design mode* for `ImageView`s and/or `Button`s (therefore without having to actually set the image with `app:srcCompat` or `android:background`).

That because I **will set the real image programmatically** in the java file.

To make an example, I mean something like `tool:text` for the `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tool:text="Here will be displayed some text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`tools` namespace anywhere** to apply an xml attribute value in the *preview mode*.

Here's an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you can see the image in the *preview mode*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just added both `tools:src="@drawable/my_icon"` to the `ImageView` and `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the root `LinearLayout` but it doesn't work :( It does not give any error though

Comment: Maybe your view is being **drawn outside the layout?** could you share your layout files?